# How do I install a GIMP plugin using 'make install'?

Tags: macos, gimp

I am trying to install ['David's Batch Processor'](http://members.ozemail.com.au/%7Ehodsond/dbp.html) in order to batch convert multiple very large folders of RAW images to jpeg. I have tried using [this](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-gimp-plugins/) guide to install the plugin, but it is very unclear what files I should move and where, since none of the files provided on the DBP website are saved as .py or SCM. The DBP website says I need "g++ and the gimp development packages for the appropriate Gimp version ". I have never used g++ or used any gimp development packages before. I feel like I'm way over my head but would like to learn how to do this!

Comment: There is a tool called [`sips`](https://robservatory.com/use-sips-to-quickly-easily-and-freely-convert-image-files/) which can convert from raw to jpeg on the command line without gimp. Even using [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=15554) might be easier. I think macos build tools ship with xode `xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`g++` is a C++ compiler (actually a thin front-end over gcc).

Normally you would just do `make; make install` but this requires some other tools such as `make` that are part of the `build-essentials` package on Linux.

DBP has a competitor (or successor, since DBP updates seem to have stopped in 2013) called [BIMP](https://alessandrofrancesconi.it/projects/bimp/), and its GitHub page has [instructions to build it on macOS](https://github.com/alessandrofrancesconi/gimp-plugin-bimp/blob/master/README.md#user-content-for-mac-osx-users). And even if you prefer DBP these instructions may apply in good part to DBP.